# Node.js - process.stdin.read()

Tags: node.js

I've just started learning node.js and have been toying around with `process.stdin` and `process.stdout`; Why is the length of the string returned by `process.stdin.read()` 1 longer than what was actually typed in?

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  var input = process.stdin.read();
  if(input !== null) {
    process.stdout.write(`stdout: ${input}\n`);
    var command = input.trim();

    console.log(input.length);  //this one is always 1 longer
    console.log(command.length);

    if(command === 'quit') {
      process.exit(0);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your input to a `Buffer` object, and see the raw data of your input. When you input `123`, `console.log(new Buffer(input))` will output `<Buffer 31 32 33 0a>`.In ASCII code table `0a` just means `Line Feed` which is the enter key you pressed.